# <nav> wont take up full width on mobile

Tags: html, css

Using Chrome Dev Tools and while being on mobile, the nav bar won't take up 100% of the screen width.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://grocerystorerblx.github.io/">Home</a></li>
      <!-- <li><a href="">Fan Art</a></li> !-->
      <li><a href="https://grocerystorerblx.github.io/devlog">Dev Log</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://grocerystorerblx.github.io/credits">Credits</a></li>
      
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <iframe width="720" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OfDQD1vwsc4?si=hYtyXVJaSg7q_fpz" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<h2>Countdown to Grocery Store 2's Release Date</h2>
<script src="https://grocerystorerblx.github.io/script.js"></script>
<h3 id="countdown"></h3>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #7AE7C7;
  text-align: center;
}

nav{
  background-color: #0b4e2d;
  font-size:18px;
  padding:6px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

On a big screen it's fine, but when on mobile it doesn't take up all of the space

I put this in the  but it still didn't work

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your iframe with its fixed width of 720px is overflowing the body. So even if the nav has 100% width it's 100% width of the body.

I have tested by setting the video to 100% and that fixes the issue.

You might play around with either reducing the iframe manually based on screen width by using media queries or using a percentage.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-color: #7ae7c7;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    nav {
      background-color: #0b4e2d;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 6px;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 10px;
      position: relative;
      color: white;
      margin-left: 15px;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://grocerystorerblx.github.io/">Home</a></li>
      <!-- <li><a href="">Fan Art</a></li> !-->
      <li><a href="https://grocerystorerblx.github.io/devlog">Dev Log</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://grocerystorerblx.github.io/credits">Credits</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <iframe width="100%" height="405" class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OfDQD1vwsc4?si=hYtyXVJaSg7q_fpz" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
    allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h2>Countdown to Grocery Store 2's Release Date</h2>
  <script src="https://grocerystorerblx.github.io/script.js"></script>
  <h3 id="countdown"></h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But I still want to keep the dimensions the same for the iframe. How would I do that?